# Vertx Web Routing base on the Localization

Tags: java, routes, localization, vert.x

Are there any easy way to done that in vertx-web?

en = english characters, cn = Simplified characters, tw = Traditional characters

```
localhost:8080/en/home
localhost:8080/cn/home
localhost:8080/tw/home

localhost:8080/en/user/mange
localhost:8080/cn/user/mange
localhost:8080/tw/user/mange
```

Do there have any generic way to switch the en/cn/tw localization path?

Comment: And why path variables are not sufficient? `router.route("/:locale/home")`

Answer (score 0):

implementation will be like this

```
        Route route = router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/:locale/home");

        route.handler(routingContext -> {

          String locale = routingContext.request().getParam("locale");

          // Do something with them...
        });



        Route route = router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/:locale/user/manage");

        route.handler(routingContext -> {

          String locale = routingContext.request().getParam("locale");

          // Do something with them...
        });
```